# To get a background image to scroll behind my other <div> columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

I have been developing a website for a family member of mine and I have the page split into columns and wrapped up in div elements,

but I can't figure out how to get the columns to sit centered over the scrolling background image,

if I put the background div element at the bottom of the page it puts the background at the bottom between the footer and all of the columns,

if I put it before the columns it just puts the image above the columns.

> How do I get the columns to sit centered over the background image?

Heres the html page and the CSS file,

(some elements in the CSS are for an img gallery on another page):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 15px solid orange;
}

html {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  background-color: white;
  border: 15px solid orange;
  padding: 15px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  background-color: #FFD700;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #DAA520;
}

.aside {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.footer {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 15px;
}


/* for mobile phones */

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /*for tablets */
  .col-m-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-m-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-m-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-m-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-m-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-m-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-m-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-m-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-m-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-m-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-m-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-m-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* for desktop */
  .col-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.active {
  background-color: #FF6347;
}

div.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.fixed-bg {
  background-image: url("IMG_0174.jpg");
  min-height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

div.container-fluid {
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid orange;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Rellim Nievk Photography©</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="kevin1.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <h1>Rellim Nievk Photography©</h1>
  </div>


  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-3 col-m-3 menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/rellim_nivek_/">Instagram</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-m-9">
      <p class=>Rellim Nievk Photography© is a photographer working out of north central Connecticut. His predominant field of expertise is automotive photography at car shows and events in and around the northeast part of the United States. He also does lots of
        general artistic photography of things like people and scenery. You may view his portfoilo here on the website, as well as on his instagram <a href="https://www.instagram.com/rellim_nivek_/">here</a></p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-3 right col-m-12 right">
      <div class="aside">
        <h2>INSERT TEXT HERE</h2>
        <p>Insert Text heer</p>
        <h2>INSERT THE TEXTS HERR YO</h2>
        <p>oooooweeee forrmatting tests!!!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="fixed-bg"></div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>©2017 Rellim Nievk Photography</p>
  </div>


  <div class="clearfix"></div>


</body>


</html>
```

Any help suggestions or insight will be greatly apperaciated!

Comment: please setup a codepen or jsfiddle to give your helpers a prepared playground

Comment: One thing to note is that you're including Bootstrap, but not jQuery which it relies on. Check the console for other errors.

Comment: Only post revelant code to your issue.

Comment: set background image on body tag, or create a wrapper div and set it there.

Comment: Please provide the minimal code required for the problem demonstration. Don't just dump all of your css and html. Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have the columns vertical centered, use the bootstrap container. always use container -> row -> column. that's the bootstrap structure.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- your content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so i would want to put the div row element inside of a div container?

Comment: word just added that in and things look much nicer thank you :)